# I have Sum column where clients is Active and group last Month Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a Relationship Many To Many to Tables clients , amperes , clients_amperes
to get sum (sum_pay) where status = 1 in Clients and where (date) last month in amperes

```
 clients  | amperes |clients_amperes 
  id      | id      |amperes_id
  name    | counts  |clients_id
  status  | date    |sum_pay
```

I used This code but not beneficial I need one value
`In Controller`

```
  $sum_is = ClientsAmpere::with('clients')
            ->where('expire_at','>',
                Carbon::today()->toDateString())
            ->get()->sum('sum_pay');
```

and this ---------

```
    $sum_is = DB::table('clients_amperes')
        ->selectRaw(DB::raw('SUM(sum_pay) as total_amount , monthname(created_at) as month'))
        ->groupBy('month')
        ->orderByRaw('min(created_at) desc')
        ->get();
```

and this ---------

```
$something = DB::table('clients_amperes')->get(['id', 'created_at','sum_pay'])->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m');
    });
    dd($something->sum('sum_pay'));
```

Comment: Please explain your question in detail :)

Comment: @S.Sachith I want the sum of the column sum_pay when the customer status is 1 and in the month of 8

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ClientAmpere::select("clients_id",DB::raw("SUM(`sum_pay`) as `total_pay`"))
->whereHas('clients',function($qry){
    $qry->where('status',1);
})
->whereMonth('created_at', date('08'))
->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
->groupby('clients_id')
->get();
```

this will returns you the sum of **sum_pay** column of the **08 month of the current year** where **client status is 1** with respect to each client

you can replace **created_at** with **expires_at** column if you are comparing dates with it